# App Testing on iPad doesn't work: process launch failed: NotFound

Tags: ipad, testing, xcode5

I was testing on my ipad my first app version. 
So that I deleted from it cause I started to work for the next one. 
Well, I deleted also organizer data and other references, provisioning profile are correct but when I try to launch my new version it doesn't start on my iPad and i see that error (in title) on Xcode.

Moreover, when i go to app installed's list i can see my app logo, memory occupied but there isn't title.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by shutting down and restarting the iPad.